# MSVS unexpected class error: Didn't forget the semicolon though

Tags: c++, class

In my code below, I get this compiler error `error C2236: unexpected 'class' 'Pawn'. Did you forget a ';'?` But as you can see plainly, I'm not missing a semicolon... am I? I used to think it was a problem due to cyclical dependencies, but I removed any includes beside the vector. This class was also supposed to inherit from my `Piece` class, but even after removing that I still get an error.

```
#ifndef CHESS_PAWN_H
#define CHESS_PAWN_H

#include <vector>

class Pawn {
private:
    bool _hasMoved;

public:
    Pawn(int x, int y);
    ~Pawn();

    std::vector<int> availMoves();
};

#endif
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this occur in a file that includes nothing but this header?

Comment: This code looks good and compiles just fine in g++. If you compile this code only, do you get the same errors? It rather seems that a previous include caused the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Extrapolating, you chess.cpp file might look like this:

```
#include "piece.h"
#include "pawn.h"
//etc..
```

The missing semicolon is located in piece.h.  Standard preprocessor lossage.

Comment: Oh wow! I never really thought about that... I went through all of my files and found that I left off 2 semicolons. After thinking it over I remembered that the preprocessor copies the the .h files when you `#include` them so that means that one of the other .h files caused the error but it wouldn't show up till later.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but is it possible the "vector" header didn't get accidentally modified at some point? I have had this happen to me where I accidentally deleted a line or character in a header file without noticing.

Post the contents of  we can take a look and see if it was modified.